# download file from bucket on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cp

I'm trying to download my file from bucket to local machine

command

```
!gsutil ls gs://bigdatapart2-storage/pickleRdd
```

will list the file
but i cannot download it to my local

I follow process as recommended on:
[CP command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)

but im getting error r=each time as below

```
RDDFromPicklepath = 'gs://bigdatapart2-storage/pickleRdd'
!gsutil cp  gs://bigdatapart2-storage/pickleRdd, RDDFromPickle
!gsutil cp RDDFromPickle, 'gs://bigdatapart2-storage/pickleRdd'
! gsutil cp 'pickleRdd' 'gs://bigdatapart2-storage/pickleRdd'/
! gsutil cp  'gs://bigdatapart2-storage/pickleRdd'/'pickleRdd' ./
```

gives error

CommandException: No URLs matched: gs://bigdatapart2-storage/pickleRdd,

CommandException: No URLs matched: RDDFromPickle,

CommandException: No URLs matched: pickleRdd

CommandException: No URLs matched: gs://bigdatapart2-storage/pickleRdd/pickleRdd

file access is  Public on the Internet

Comment: This should work: `gsutil cp  gs://bigdatapart2-storage/pickleRdd ./`. If the actual file is `pickleRdd`. Not sure why you have to add those extra `,` or `/`.

Comment: Is there a file named pickleRdd or is it a directory? If it's a directory, you'll need to use the `-r` flag.

Comment: work well thanks !